# can't add the CoreData.framework to my exisiting project

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

I'm new to stackoverflow.
Here is my problem...I just can't add CoreData.framework to my existing project. 
I cliced on the Frameworks group pressing the control button. The menu is supposed to show
 Add->Exisiting Framewokrs...right? , but no matter how I tried, the Add option didn't show on the menu. The menu shows:
Open As
New File
New Project
New Group
New Group from selection
Add Files to "xxxxxx"...
Delete
Source Control
Project Navigator Help
So, can someone tell me how I proceed from here...?
Thank you...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your are using xcode 4.2:

- Select your application target
- Select "Build Phases" tab
- Under "link binary with libraries" click [+]
- choose CoreData from the list
- click add